# How to convert a table with per-minute data into a table with hourly data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a table with minute data. Some rows are missing in this table.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
("2019-02-15 17:56:00", 11, 10),
("2019-02-15 17:57:00", 22, 10),
("2019-02-15 18:00:00", 33, 20),
("2019-02-15 18:01:00", 44, 20),
("2019-02-15 18:02:00", 55, 20),
("2019-02-16 10:01:00", 66, 50),
("2019-02-16 10:02:00", 77, 50)],
columns=["date_time", "last_val", "sum_val"])
```

[image: Table with minute data]

I need to get a table with hourly data. Where in the `last_val` column will be the last value in an hour. And in the `sum_val` column there will be the sum of all values per hour.

To make the resulting table look like this:

[image: Table with hourly data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your groupkey is not very easy to find , first need slice the `date_time` till `hour` and convert back to `datetime` object , then just `groupby` it with `agg`

```
groupkey=pd.to_datetime(df.date_time.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H'))
df.groupby(groupkey).agg({'last_val':'last','sum_val':'sum'})
Out[141]: 
                     last_val  sum_val
date_time                             
2019-02-15 17:00:00        22       20
2019-02-15 18:00:00        55       60
2019-02-16 10:00:00        77      100
```

Comment: I’ll add to other people that at the beginning of your code we can also add a line: `df["date_time"]=pd.to_datetime(df["date_time"])`. And in the end: `df.reset_index()`.